# TCP connection pauses for a long time then restarts

Tags: tcp, connection, freeze

I have an ubuntu 18.04 vbox hosted on a windows PC and bridged to the gigabit wired connection.
From chrome running on the windows PC I invoke a graphql api on the Ubuntu VM. The graphql returns about 3MB of data and everything is working fine.

The windows PC is in a DMZ and I can invoke the graphql API from another PC in another place (remotely). Iperf3 tells me that I have about 10-15 Mbit/s bandwidth when connecting remotely.

Anyway, when I try to invoke the graphql API it happens that the TCP connection (on port 4000) after transferring about 700kB seems to pause for a long time (about 70-80 secs) and the it restarts. Sometimes all the transfer is performed but not all the times.

This is a capture that shows the "pause":

[image]

I played with the TCP window size (reducing it) to no avail.

Comment: You can test yourself using this command: wget http://mccfm.duckdns.org:7777/pippo.wav   It goes fast till 600-700 kB have been downloaded and then hangs.

Answer (score 0):

I did several tests with different web servers, also with an Ubuntu VM using VMWARE and finally I got the problem. I had to remove "LiveQoS NDIS 6 Filter Driver" from the windows ethernet interface stack. 
This "LiveQoS NDIS 6 Filter Driver" causes many problems when using virtual machines.
If you need other info I will be glad to help.